# Ruby TestCase: Define instance variable in `self.startup` method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium, oop, inheritance

I have this Ruby code:

```js
class GoogleTestCase < BaseTestCase

    def test_search
        @browser.find_element(:name, 'q').send_keys "Hello Ruby"
        @browser.find_element(:name, 'btnK')
    end

end
```

And then I run the GoogleTestCase through this file:

```js
...

class BaseTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def self.startup
        @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
        @browser.get('https://google.com')
    end

    def self.shutdown
        @browser.quit
    end
end

exit Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run(true, test_dir)
```

After launching, everything is fine. Selenium will run Chrome browser, it opens Google web page. But when the `test_search` method is fired, Ruby can't see `@browser` variable: 
[image: console output with error]

How can I define `@browser` variable in `self.startup` method so inside the `test_search` method I can see it?

Comment: Instead of the class methods `startup` and `shutdown`, you could use the instance methods `setup` and `teardown`. Or use a [class variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Class+Variables), i.e. `@@browser`.

Comment: No I can't. Because `setup` method behave differently than `startup` method. `Startup` is called only once, but `setup` before every test method of the class. And I don't want that.

Comment: "or use a class variable"

Comment: Ok thanks. So If I want to use instance variable (instead of class variable), isn't it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem you are trying to solve. What's wrong with a class variable?

Comment: What if I will try to run several TestCases in the same time (multi-thread)? They will share the same `@@browser` and they will try to do several different stuff with it. Class variables seem like bad-practise for this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want a browser that is shared between the instances or one browser per instance? Or something in-between?

Comment: I want one browser per one **instance**. So I need **instance** variable. You offered me **class** variable. P.S. I also really want to use `startup` method, not `setup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you try to access instance variable `@browser`, which is defined on class level. Because `startup` and `shutdown` are class methods, `@browser` is class variable accordingly.

You can use `@@browser` to access class variables from instance level.

```
class GoogleTestCase < BaseTestCase

    def test_search
        @@browser.find_element(:name, 'q').send_keys "Hello Ruby"
        @@browser.find_element(:name, 'btnK')
    end

end
```

Keep in mind, that `@@browser` is the same across all instances of such class.

Also, you can encapsulate the way you access the browser variable in helper method:

```
class BaseTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def self.startup
        @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
        @browser.get('https://google.com')
    end

    def self.shutdown
        @browser.quit
    end

    def browser
      @@browser
    end
end

class GoogleTestCase < BaseTestCase

    def test_search
        browser.find_element(:name, 'q').send_keys "Hello Ruby"
        browser.find_element(:name, 'btnK')
    end

end
```